# Dynamic Spring xml

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Im trying to implement a load balancer using Apache Camel and Spring.

To do so, one has to configure the target servers in a spring.xml like this:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="localhost:8000"/>
    <loadBalance>        
      <roundRobin/>
      <to uri="localhost:8080"/>        
      <to uri="localhost:8081"/>       
      <to uri="localhost:8082"/>                 
    </loadBalance>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

Now, is there a way to read in all target servers from a properties file?
Just so one could change them without editing the spring.xml...

Answer (score 1):

As your describe, I think the recipient-list(http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) can solve your problem.

You can decide which uri to be sent in the java code, things like read servers from a properties file can be easily done.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple choices available to do that:

- http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html
- http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html
- Starting from Camel 2.16 you can also use "dynamic to" (http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html)